# Horizontal scroll layout

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I don't know if this is too obvious question or too abstract, but this days I saw a very interesting layout. It was a WebMail system, with 3 columns:

the first occupying 20% of my screen and containing the folders (inbox, spam, etc...) of my account.

the second occupying 30% of my screen, containing the messages list inside the folder.

and the third occupying 50% of my screen, with the message contents...

Ok, on my computer nothing interesting, but when I saw it on my cellphone, this was amazingly responsive. Each time I saw only one column, that fits perfectly my screen width, once I click in some folder it rolls horizontally to the next column and I select a message and it rolls for the message contents... I was looking at Google and trying to find something to do this on bootstrap or jQuery, but I didn't found anything. The best I found was RainLoop WebMail that have a design apparently like this one.
Someone know if bootstrap of jQuery have support for this kind of layout? How should I proceed to achieve something like this?

Sorry for the lack of code, but I have no idea how to do this.

[Screenshots of RainLoop layout](http://www.rainloop.net/screenshots/)

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure I fully understand the question, but I'll try to explain what I think you want to do.

My understanding is that you want something that is divided into 3 columns on tablet/pc acts like a "slider" on mobile devices. I assume you know how to create something that fills the entire screen. If not, you will want to look at bootstrap framework for achieving this, or just use width attributes with media queries.

The next step would simply be to offset the "boxes" of content, and then use jQuery

```
    $(".mail-folder-item-1").on("click",function(){

  $("#mail-list").slideLeft(300);
  $("#mail-folder").slideLeft(300);


});
```

This would slide your folder content to the left and your mail-list to the left into view. You would as mentioned earlier have to initally offset the mail-list box with appropriate means (css/jQuery).

Finally you will need something that understands what is clicked and can find that in the list, wich is something that should be done on the backend (server-side) according to me. This is because its a lot of logic and the server sits right on top of it, but I may be wrong on this.

Simply put, if the layout is hard then this is probably a little to big of a chunk to chew at this point of you development career, but I urge you to try your best! Hope this helps, please respond for clarification.

Comment: Yes, right now I can feel that the question was abstract, but I haven't anything further to provide. I'm not a designer coder myself, CSS is not my strong skill. So I did this question to raise some theories about how to get this. You gave me one of them, I need to try this and see what can be done. Thank you